# Hide div if i found 0,00€ in my body page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to disable other div if in other div I have `0,00€`.

Example: I have div `.buy` with button of payment, and I have div `.price` with string `0,00€`.

I need to disable `.buy` if my `price` is `0,00€`.

I need a jQuery generic, because I have created a website with WordPress. I have used TM Global Extra Products Option for Woocommerce, I have insert select at 0€, but when i enter in products, I see button for payment with 0€, and i want to disable button if price is 0€

```
<form class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<div id="tm-extra-product-options" class="tm-extra-product-options tm-custom-prices tm-product-id-4364 tm-cart-main" data-product-id="4364" data-cart-id="main">
<div class="tm-totals-form-main" data-product-id="4364">
<input class="cpf-product-price" type="hidden" name="cpf_product_price" value="0">
<div id="tm-epo-totals" class="tm-epo-totals tm-custom-prices-total tm-cart-main" data-variations="[]" data-variations-subscription-period="[]" data-subscription-period="" data-variations-subscription-sign-up-fee="[]" data-subscription-sign-up-fee="0" data-prices-include-tax="" data-tax-display-mode="excl" data-tax-string="" data-tax-rate="22" data-taxable="1" data-force-quantity="0" data-tm-epo-dpd-suffix="" data-tm-epo-dpd-prefix="" data-fields-price-rules="0" data-product-price-rules="[]" data-price="0" data-type="simple" data-is-sold-individually="" data-is-subscription="" data-cart-id="main" data-theme-name="Blusign">
<dl class="tm-extra-product-options-totals tm-custom-price-totals">
<dt class="tm-options-totals">Options amount</dt>
<dd class="tm-options-totals">
<dt class="tm-final-totals">Prezzo Totale:</dt>
<dd class="tm-final-totals">
<span class="amount final">0,00€</span>
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>
<div class="iva_esc">
<div class="quantity">
<input type="hidden" value="4364" name="add-to-cart">
<button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit" style="display: block;">Vai al pagamento</button>
</form
```

Comment: Well we need some basic HTML to help you out. Basic operation is select the elements, loop over, check text, if yes, find related element and hide...

Comment: You need to try something before posting. We can't help without any code.

Comment: `if(price == 0){ do something } else{...}` - *ecco! cè non troppo difficile*

Comment: Will help you to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple jQuery script that checks if all prices are zero, and if so disables the button.

```js
function updateCheckoutState() {
  //check if all items are zero
  var disable = $(".cart span.amount.final").toArray().every(function(item) {
    return $(item).text() === "0,00€";
  });

  //disable button if necessary
  $(".cart button.single_add_to_cart_button").prop("disabled", disable);
}

$(function() {
  updateCheckoutState();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div id="tm-extra-product-options" class="tm-extra-product-options tm-custom-prices tm-product-id-4364 tm-cart-main" data-product-id="4364" data-cart-id="main">
    <div class="tm-totals-form-main" data-product-id="4364">
      <input class="cpf-product-price" type="hidden" name="cpf_product_price" value="0">
      <div id="tm-epo-totals" class="tm-epo-totals tm-custom-prices-total tm-cart-main" data-variations="[]" data-variations-subscription-period="[]" data-subscription-period="" data-variations-subscription-sign-up-fee="[]" data-subscription-sign-up-fee="0" data-prices-include-tax="" data-tax-display-mode="excl" data-tax-string="" data-tax-rate="22" data-taxable="1" data-force-quantity="0" data-tm-epo-dpd-suffix="" data-tm-epo-dpd-prefix="" data-fields-price-rules="0" data-product-price-rules="[]" data-price="0" data-type="simple" data-is-sold-individually="" data-is-subscription="" data-cart-id="main" data-theme-name="Blusign">
        <dl class="tm-extra-product-options-totals tm-custom-price-totals">
          <dt class="tm-options-totals">Options amount</dt>
          <dd class="tm-options-totals">
          <dt class="tm-final-totals">Prezzo Totale:</dt>
          <dd class="tm-final-totals">
            <span class="amount final">0,00€</span>
          </dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="iva_esc">
      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="hidden" value="4364" name="add-to-cart">
        <button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit" style="display: block;">Vai al pagamento</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I updated the script so it works with the HTML you supplied. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, this code work, but now button was always disable, how i can active if price not is 0,00€?

Comment: I updated the example and created a function named `updateCheckoutState()`. It is currently being called when the page loads. You can call that function whenever your price is updated and the function will enable/disable the checkout button as necessary. Your code doesn't show that part, so I can't show you exactly how to hook it in.

Comment: I have try with your new code but don't see button active, only disable.

Comment: You need to call the function when the prices are updated. I can't tell how that might happen from the code you posted.